# How do I call an unmanaged function that has a char[] as OUT parameter from C#?

Tags: c#, .net, c, pinvoke, marshalling

Say, I've got that prototype of a function that is exposed on a DLL:

```
int CALLBACK worker (char* a_inBuf, int a_InLen,
                     char** a_pOutBuf, int* a_pOutLen,
                     char** a_pErrBuf, int* a_pErrLen)
```

I'm sure that it's ridiculously easy to call that DLL function from my C# code but it doesn't work with this code:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll")]  
     public static extern int worker(
         [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] inBuf,  
         int inputLen,  
         [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] outBuf,  
         out int outputLen,  
         [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] errBuf,  
         out int errorLen);

... 

int outputXmlLength = 0;
int errorXmlLength  = 0;

byte[]  outputXml = null;
byte[]  errorXml  = null;
worker(input, input.Length, output, out outputLength, error, out errorLength);
```

I get an access violation when I'm going to fetch the memory for `output` and `error` inside my unmanaged library (and therefore de-reference the passed pointer):

```
*a_ppBuffer = (char*) malloc(size*sizeof(char));
```

1. How do I write the `DLLIMPORT` statement in my C# code for this function?
2. How do I actually call the function so that `a_pOutBuf` and `a_pErrBuf` are accessible and not `null` from within `worker` (i.e. use a real double pointer)?

Comment: Can you change the worker function signature?

Comment: @SimonMourier: no. it's a DLL used in a C++ program (established API) and should now also be called from a freshly developed .net application. Therefore the API is fixed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your current definition will not work.  The `worker` function is allocating memory inside of the function and writing to that memory.

The [P/Invoke layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzhhdwae.aspx) does not support marshaling C-style arrays that are allocated in this way, as it has no way of knowing just how large the array will be when the call returns (unlike say, a [`SAFEARRAY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221482%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

That's also why returning pointers to arrays from API functions is generally a bad idea, and the Windows API is written in such a way that the memory allocation is handled by the *caller*.

That said, you want to change the P/Invoke declaration of `worker` to this:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll")]  
public static extern int worker(
    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] inBuf,  
    int inputLen,  
    ref IntPtr outBuf, 
    ref int outputLen,  
    ref IntPtr errBuf, 
    ref int errorLen
);
```

In doing this, you're indicating that you're going to marshal the arrays manually (the `outBuf` and `errBuf` parameters are going to be set for you); you're passing the reference to the pointer (double-indirection, that's your `char**`) and then have to read from them using other indicators for bounds checking (in this case, the `outputLen` and `errorLen` parameters).

You would marshal the data out of the pointers upon return like so:

```
int outputXmlLength = 0;
int errorXmlLength  = 0;

IntPtr output = IntPtr.Zero;
IntPtr error = IntPtr.Zero;

worker(
    input, 
    input.Length, 
    ref output, 
    ref outputLength, 
    ref error, 
    ref errorLength
);

// Get the strings.
string outputString = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(
    output, 
    outputLength
);
string errorString = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(
    error, 
    errorLength
);
```

That said, you have another problem.  Because the memory was allocated inside the function, you have to free the memory.  Since you're using `malloc` to allocate the memory, you need to pass the two `IntPtr` instances back to unmanaged code in order to have `free` called on them.

If you were allocating memory in unmanaged code using [`LocalAlloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366723.aspx) or [`CoTaskMemAlloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692727%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) then you could use the [`FreeHGlobal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.freehglobal.aspx) or [`FreeCoTaskMem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.freecotaskmem.aspx) methods respectively on the [`Marshal` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.aspx) to free the memory on the managed side.

Comment: I've already got a `cleanup(void)` method which is used to clean up the allocated memory. The assumption (that is working under unmanaged `C++`) is that the state of my DLL will not change between calling `worker` and `cleanup`. The state is held internally.

Comment: nope. The method takes exactly **no** parameters because there is other stuff stored until `cleanup` is called.

Comment: @eckes So you're tracking the pointers that you're handing out?  If that's the case, then the last two paragraphs don't apply, but the rest of the answer does.

Comment: This helped me out after frustrating over such a subtle change... was converting `char**` incorrectly to `out string` instead of `ref IntPtr` which is the correct reference..