# How to connect C++ dll using c#

Tags: c#, c++

I have a problem while calling a function of a C++ dll using C#?
I have a C++ dll, with a function like as below

```
 int getresult ( char *a, int *b, char *c, int *d)
```

Here I need to pass value to parameter `a` and parameter `b` and I will get back the result in parameter `c` and parameter `d`.

I'm able to get the return value from the function using C# but not the `c` and `d` value. Here the C# Code that I use:

```
namespace Test
{
class Program
{
    [DllImport(@"C:\test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int getresult(string a, int b, out string c, out int d);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i;
        string a = "1234test123";
        string c;
        int b = 11;
        int d;
        try
        {
            i = getresult(a, b, out c, out d);
            if (c != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("i " + i + " c= " + c);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Completed");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error " + ex.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Can anybody help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you *please* properly format your code as code and your text as not-code, not the other way around?

Comment: Do you mean that `getresult` _writes_ to `c` and `d`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457375/how-do-i-call-an-unmanaged-function-that-has-a-char-as-out-parameter-from-c

Comment: what do you get as result for the variable c

Comment: I will get a some string as a response along with non printable characters.

Comment: yes getresult will writes the result to c and d

Comment: Lots and lots of mistakes, the very poorly named function arguments do not help.  CharSet.Auto is wrong, must be Ansi.  int b is wrong, must be ref int b.  out string is wrong, strings are immutable, must be StringBuilder (no out).  Not being to specify the size of the c buffer is a drastic mistake and likely to get the C++ code to corrupt memory when it writes too much.  That the C++ code doesn't crash like it should with these bad declarations would be another reason why you get no data back, be sure you can debug it.